# Traversing DOM from span in / out of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal

I'm adding a click event to a span that is within a div. The target of this event, which will become visible, is a first div that is within a div, two divs down. How can I traverse the DOM to find it?

Perhaps it'll be clearer with the code:

```
<div a>
    <h2>
        <span id="here">Click</span>
    </h2>
</div>

<div></div>

<div>
    <div class="targetDiv">This is the div we need to find</div>
    <div class="targetDiv">There are other divs with the same id, but we don't need to find   those</div>
    <div class="targetDiv">Not looking for this one </div>
    <div class="targetDiv">Or this one either</div>
</div>
```

I've searched left and right and cannot find an answer. It's important to restrict the event ONLY to the first div immediately after the span.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Apart from the text within the div you're looking for, what else differentiates them? If they are as posted, and cannot be changed, you should state that in your question.

Comment: in your page, are there other divs that contain a similar structure? are there other spans that do the same thing as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. I provided an example you can just save to a html file and test it yourself

```
<style>
.targetDiv{display:none;}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#here').click(function(){
$('.targetDiv').first().show(); // or whatever you want
});
});
</script>

<div a>
    <h2>
        <span id="here">Click</span>
    </h2>
</div>

<div></div>

<div>
    <div class="targetDiv">This is the div we need to find</div>
    <div class="targetDiv">There are other divs with the same id, but we don't need to find   those</div>
    <div class="targetDiv">Not looking for this one </div>
    <div class="targetDiv">Or this one either</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, indeed. I didn't know how to find selectors moving forward in the DOM. All I could find was parents and closest. This helps.

Answer (score 2):

As shown, the code would look like this:

```
$('span#here').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').siblings(':contains(.targetDiv)').children().eq(0).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/npVj4/1/) of the fish we caught

```
$(function() {
    $('#here').on('click', function() {
        var div = $(this)          //the element clicked
            .closest('div')        //find nearest parent div
            .nextAll(':eq(1)')     //find the second next div
            .children(':eq(0)')    //find the first child of it
            .show();               //remove invisible cloak
    });
});​
```

Comment: I was thinking of this as a possible alternative. Tested the code but it didn't work. I'll try again and update you if I get it to work this way. Thanks.